# Flight offers price API returns internal error when called using the python-sdk

Tags: python, amadeus

I'm trying the Amadeus python-sdk. When I call the flight offers price api:

```
amadeus.post('/v1/shopping/flight-offers/pricing', body)
```

I get this response:

```
{
   "errors":[
      {
         "code":"38189",
         "title":"Internal error",
         "detail":"An internal error occurred, please contact your administrator",
         "status":"500"
      }
   ]
}
```

This is the body I used:

```
body = {'data': {'type': 'flight-offers-pricing', 'flightOffers': [{'type': 'flight-offer', 'id': '1', 'source': 'GDS', 'instantTicketingRequired': False, 'nonHomogeneous': False, 'oneWay': False, 'lastTicketingDate': '2020-03-01', 'numberOfBookableSeats': 4, 'itineraries': [{'duration': 'PT14H10M', 'segments': [{'departure': {'iataCode': 'GIG', 'at': '2020-03-01T23:30:00'}, 'arrival': {'iataCode': 'CMN', 'terminal': '2', 'at': '2020-03-02T12:10:00'}, 'carrierCode': 'AT', 'number': '212', 'aircraft': {'code': '788'}, 'operating': {'carrierCode': 'AT'}, 'id': '3', 'numberOfStops': 0, 'blacklistedInEU': False}, {'departure': {'iataCode': 'CMN', 'terminal': '2', 'at': '2020-03-02T15:45:00'}, 'arrival': {'iataCode': 'MAD', 'terminal': '4S', 'at': '2020-03-02T17:40:00'}, 'carrierCode': 'AT', 'number': '970', 'aircraft': {'code': '73G'}, 'operating': {'carrierCode': 'AT'}, 'id': '4', 'numberOfStops': 0, 'blacklistedInEU': False}]}, {'duration': 'PT31H20M', 'segments': [{'departure': {'iataCode': 'MAD', 'terminal': '4S', 'at': '2020-03-05T18:40:00'}, 'arrival': {'iataCode': 'CMN', 'terminal': '2', 'at': '2020-03-05T20:30:00'}, 'carrierCode': 'AT', 'number': '971', 'aircraft': {'code': '738'}, 'operating': {'carrierCode': 'AT'}, 'id': '47', 'numberOfStops': 0, 'blacklistedInEU': False}, {'departure': {'iataCode': 'CMN', 'terminal': '2', 'at': '2020-03-06T16:40:00'}, 'arrival': {'iataCode': 'GIG', 'at': '2020-03-06T22:00:00'}, 'carrierCode': 'AT', 'number': '213', 'aircraft': {'code': '788'}, 'operating': {'carrierCode': 'AT'}, 'id': '48', 'numberOfStops': 0, 'blacklistedInEU': False}]}], 'price': {'currency': 'USD', 'total': '2778.98', 'base': '2568.00', 'fees': [{'amount': '0.00', 'type': 'SUPPLIER'}, {'amount': '0.00', 'type': 'TICKETING'}]}, 'pricingOptions': {'fareType': ['PUBLISHED'], 'includedCheckedBagsOnly': True}, 'validatingAirlineCodes': ['AT'], 'travelerPricings': [{'travelerId': '1', 'fareOption': 'STANDARD', 'travelerType': 'ADULT', 'price': {'currency': 'USD', 'total': '1625.49', 'base': '1520.00'}, 'fareDetailsBySegment': [{'segmentId': '3', 'cabin': 'BUSINESS', 'fareBasis': 'DA0R0BRA', 'class': 'D', 'includedCheckedBags': {'quantity': 3}}, {'segmentId': '4', 'cabin': 'BUSINESS', 'fareBasis': 'DA0R0BRA', 'class': 'D', 'includedCheckedBags': {'quantity': 3}}, {'segmentId': '47', 'cabin': 'ECONOMY', 'fareBasis': 'XL0R0BRA', 'class': 'X', 'includedCheckedBags': {'quantity': 2}}, {'segmentId': '48', 'cabin': 'ECONOMY', 'fareBasis': 'XL0R0BRA', 'class': 'X', 'includedCheckedBags': {'quantity': 2}}]}, {'travelerId': '2', 'fareOption': 'STANDARD', 'travelerType': 'CHILD', 'price': {'currency': 'USD', 'total': '1153.49', 'base': '1048.00'}, 'fareDetailsBySegment': [{'segmentId': '3', 'cabin': 'BUSINESS', 'fareBasis': 'DA0R0BRACH', 'class': 'D'}, {'segmentId': '4', 'cabin': 'BUSINESS', 'fareBasis': 'DA0R0BRACH', 'class': 'D'}, {'segmentId': '47', 'cabin': 'ECONOMY', 'fareBasis': 'XL0R0BRACH', 'class': 'X'}, {'segmentId': '48', 'cabin': 'ECONOMY', 'fareBasis': 'XL0R0BRACH', 'class': 'X'}]}]}]}}
```

I tested the same request with postman and it worked. Any idea what could be causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: This is an internal server error (an error in the API server implementation), as clearly mentionned in the error message. IOW, only someone having access to the server's logs and source code could tell you what went wrong. Hence the obvious advice used as "detail" field: "please contact your administrator" (IOW: contact the Amadeus support).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about an internal server error on the Amadeus API server, so the OP should have just done what the error message says; contact amadeus admins.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.
First, I already contacted Amadeus support.
Second, since I only get the internal error when using the python-sdk, my guess was that the problem comes from the sdk itself and not from the server. I was right, the request made through the sdk was missing a header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem.
First, I checked the headers and body of the request:

```
amadeus.post('/v1/shopping/flight-offers/pricing', data)
```

Using this code

```
try:
    pricing = amadeus.post('/v1/shopping/flight-offers/pricing', body)
    print(pricing.result)
except ResponseError as error:
    print('headers: ', error.response.request.headers)   
    print('body: ', error.response.request.params)
```

These are the headers I get:

```
{
'User-Agent': 'amadeus-python/3.1.0 python/3.6.8', 
'Accept': 'application/json, application/vnd.amadeus+json',
'Authorization': 'Bearer ...'
}
```

While according to their [postman collection](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/2672636/RWEcPfuJ?version=latest#c740eac4-f0ec-4b76-80a9-0b5bb1fe1c03) the Content-Type header is required.
I cloned the [repo](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-python) and added the Content-Type header to the post request and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK has been updated to fix this problem. You can install the new version (3.2.0).